# Casting from Int32 to 'Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.VertexShader'

Tags: vb.net

How to solved error 
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.VertexShader'

We want to case ''System.Int32' value into 'Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.VertexShader'
I tried with CType but not working.
Also tried 
mD3DDevice.VertexShader = CObj(D3DFVF_CUSTOMVERTEX_BOX)
 but no luck
 Can you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.VertexShader` is a class, a reference-type, not a value type. You cannot directly convert a `System.Int32` to a `VertexShader`, as `VertexShader` isn't based on `System.Int32` and there is no predefined conversion.
If you can think of a legitimate way to convert a `System.Int32` to a `VertexShader`, you can implement the conversion yourself.

Otherwise, it seems you should either:

1. Consult the VertexShader
   [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms863052.aspx), and specifically
   its [constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms863056.aspx) documentation.
2. Use a specific device's
       [Device.GetVertexShaderInt32Constant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms896949.aspx)
       and
       [Device.SetVertexShaderConstantInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms897024.aspx)
       methods.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
Its 9.15 PM and Its Time to leave....will try Tomorrow.
Thanks...!!!